# Firefox killed by sigbus while running inside Docker

Tags: docker, firefox

Firefox killed by SIGBUS kernel alert in Redhat Linux. Or once you start looking into Firefox logs you find out "A content process crashed Firefox" followed by connection errors seen in firefox.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox crashes is probably because the memory limit for /dev/shm inside the container is too small
Increasing this memory will solve the crash due to SIGBUS.

Add --shm-size "1g" while starting a docker container.

In docker-compose

```
services:
  yourservice:
    build:
      context: ./docker
    shm_size: '1gb'
```

More details in bugzilla.
[https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245239][1]