# Missing Dependency Docker glibc ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S

Tags: docker, ubuntu, glibc

I'm trying to run an application in a Ubuntu 20.04 docker container. It launches but soon crashes.

Using GDB I've tracked it down to this

```
Thread 36 "Emuthread - Sta" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fff57fff700 (LWP 7323)]
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S:214
214     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
```

It seems like it's missing this library

I've messed around with trying to install the MultiArch Ubuntu dev packages but not luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like it's missing this library

Nothing is missing here (other than the source code for `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms()`).

[Google "docker memset sigbus"](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker%20memset%20sigbus) yields many hits. I suggest starting with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62221600/50617).

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. That link talks about increasing shared memory space. How does that relate to missing source? A few searches talk about the host kernel being hardened being the problem but I'm just running plain Ubuntu in the host

Comment: @patrick_corrigan The "missing source" has nothing to do with the problem. It's only needed if you want to do source-level debugging of the `memset` implementation.

Comment: Ah thank you very much my friend. I really appreciate your help. Going to increase the shared memory size and see what happens. Thank you again. Will report back